# How to figure out the process/Task associated with unix process LWP

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jira

Environment :  JIRA Application running on Linux Suse/Tomcat Server

ps -Lo pcpu,pid,lwp $procnumber | sort | tail -3

> %CPU   PID   LWP
>   24.6 21133 **21152**
>   24.7 21133 **21151**
>   24.7 21133 **21153**

Now after converting LWP into Hexadecimal and then when I am trying to search that in Java Threads, I am not finding any thread dumps(JAVA) or process associated with it.

Is there any way to figure out which thread is taking away most of our CPU ?

Comment: How are you searching through the dump? The hex could be in uppercase or lowercase... try searching for both variants.

Comment: You got me...THanks

Does it mean that all LWP have to be associated with Java Thread ?

Comment: Great! I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: No, it is the other way around. Java Thread map to LWS threads on Linux (I am not sure if this is always the case!) as this varies between operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Search the thread dumps for the hex in both uppercase and lowercase format.